# Excel - Is it possible to set or change the "theme fonts" with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, fonts

In the ribbon menu under "page layout", there is a [menu point which gives the user the ability to set a header and body font document-wide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-in-word-or-excel-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904).

I would like to use VBA to set that option for multiple documents at once.

Regardless of the syntax, which I haven't figured out yet, the official docs say the properties are read-only ([header font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.themefontscheme.majorfont) and [body font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.themefontscheme.minorfont)). Is this a fruitless undertaking or is there some arguably hack-y way to achieve this, i.e. getting to the point where it is possible to write something akin to

```
Application.MajorThemeFont.Name ="Arial"
```

?

Or does one have to somehow [load an already existing theme](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/office.themefontscheme.load) into a (already existing) workbook?

Answer (score 2):

In Ribbon "Developer" TAB press "Record Macro", and then set Font, Color or Theme and the Code will be written.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what bearing this has on theme fonts?

Comment: You record your moves to get VBA code. Start recording, select any Theme, color or/and font, then stop recording and in Module1 you will see VBA Code. Running this code will do same thing you did while recording.

Answer (score 0):

Great help this question! I think the correct answer to the question should be:

You can't define the theme fonts using VBA/macro but you can **load an existing theme** using VBA.

This has worked for me:

```
   Dim pathappdata As String
   pathappdata = Environ("APPDATA")
   'theme is located at %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Fonts
    wb.Theme.ThemeFontScheme.Load ( _
        pathappdata & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Fonts\MY theme fonts.xml" _
        )
```